# How can i get incremental counter with sql?

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-redshift

Can you help me with sql query to get the desired result

Database used :- Redshift 
requirement is 
I have 3 columns as:-  dish_id,cateogory_id,counter
So i want counter to increase +1 if the dish_id is repeated and if not it should remain 1
the query i need should be able to query the source table and get the results as

`dish_id category_id  counter
    21      4          1
    21      6          2
    21      6          3
    12      1          1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless I missunderstood your question, you can accomplish that using [window functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/tutorial-window.html):

```
SELECT *,row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY dish_id) FROM my_table;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ,
This is what is looking for